# Java regex grouping

Tags: java, regex

I have the following entry in a properties file:

```
some.key = \n
  [1:Some value] \n
  [14:Some other value] \n
  [834:Yet another value] \n
```

I am trying to parse it using a regular expression, but I can't seem to get the grouping correct.  I am trying to print out a key/value for each entry.  Example: Key="834", Value="Yet another value"

```
private static final String REGEX_PATTERN = "[(\\d+)\\:(\\w+(\\s)*)]+";

private void foo(String propValue){
    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX_PATTERN);
    final Matcher m = p.matcher(propValue);
    while (m.find()) {
        final String key = m.group(0).trim();
        final String value = m.group(1).trim();
        System.out.println(String.format("Key[%s] Value[%s]", key, value));            
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

```
Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 1
```

I thought I was grouping correctly in the regex but I guess not.  Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

UPDATE:
Escaping the brackets worked.  Changed the pattern to the followingThanks for the feedback!

```
 private static final String REGEX_PATTERN = "\\[(\\d+)\\:(\\w+(\\w|\\s)*)\\]+";
```

Comment: Index out of bounds: checking for an element in the array that does not exist. Probably pointed to an unsetted index

Comment: Alfabravo - Yes, I am aware, but I am curious why the regular expression is incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[` should be escaped (as well as `]`).

```
"\\[(\\d+)....\\]+"
```

`[]` Is used for character classes: `[0-9]` == `(0|1|2|...|9)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
private static final String REGEX_PATTERN = "\\[(\\d+):([\\w\\s]+)\\]";

final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX_PATTERN);
final Matcher m = p.matcher(propValue);
while (m.find()) {
    final String key = m.group(1).trim();
    final String value = m.group(2).trim();
    System.out.println(String.format("Key[%s] Value[%s]", key, value));
}
```

1. the `[` and `]` need to be escaped because they represent the start and end of a character class
2. `group(0)` is always the full match, so your groups should start with 1
3. note how I wrote the second group `[\\w\\s]+`. This means a character class of word or whitespace characters

Answer (score 1):

It's your regex, `[]` are special characters and need to be escaped if you want to interpret them literally.

Try

```
"\\[(\\d+)\\:(\\w+(\\s)*)\\]"
```

Note - I removed the '+'. The matcher will keep finding substrings that match the pattern so the `+` is not necessary. (You might need to feed in a GLOBAL switch -  I can't remember).

I can't help but feel this might be simpler without regex though, perhaps by splitting on `\n` or `[` and then splitting on `:` for each of those.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using string that consists of several lines you should tell it to `Pattern`:

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX_PATTERN, Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

Although it is irrelevant directly for you I'd recommend you to add `DOTALL` too:

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX_PATTERN, Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Comment: The multiline thing is only important if you want to detect start/end of line. Probably a good idea to do so, though.